# A perfect information game with several millions of unique states

Tags: models

I want to model learning by having computer players compete against each other. Win/lose ratio will be tracked for each position for each player and used to search an optimal move. The depth of search and the learning rate will be two parameters characterizing a player. Which games have a relatively small set of unique states (1M-100M would be ideal), perfect information and decent length of a game?

Comment: Tic... Tac... Toe.

Comment: The reason your last question was closed was because it was too broad; list-generation questions like that don't have a single objective answer, every answer is equally valid. This is explicitly something considered off-topic per the [help]. *This* question is just a restatement of the first one.

Comment: @Josh Petrie, It seems that mini-checkers is a good way to go. Having a list tic-tac-toe-> mini-checkers-> 5 in a line -> chess->Go -> Starcraft to guide beginners would be useful.

Comment: Just because something is useful, unfortunately, doesn't make it on-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mini-checkers should work. Played on 6x6 board on half of the cells. Checker that reach last line wins the game (not get flipped). Thus each cell in the first and last raw can be empty or home-player. Other 3x4 cells each can be empty, white or black. 2^6*3^12 is < 35 M. Game can last more than 10 moves.